# To store Values in session in static method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a static method on every button click i want to store username in a session.So the session hold multiple values.And I have to check the same value exists in session for more than three times .Pls help me.

Inside Static Method:

//Button CLick

```
string[] a = new string[] { username };
 HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] = a;
 string[] data = (string[])HttpContext.Current.Session["User"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are after here... but if you want to see how many times something has appeared you could use a [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) which will store the value and the corresponding amount of *hits* for that value:

```
string username = ...;
Dictionary<string, int> values = (Dictionary<string, int>)HttpContext.Current.Session["User"];
if(values.ContainsKey(username))
    values[username]++;
else
    values.Add(username, 1);
```